# How to make a method executed always by the server in spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have to make a method in spring project which gets executed always without interfering of the user.
In fact, my application's main goal is to send emails every specified time without clicking a button.
Just the system sending the emails after configuring the database of emails.

Comment: You can schedule executions using quartz http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Scheduled` annotation to trigger a method invocation. See the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled